# How is the complexity of below O(log n) and not O(n)

Tags: time-complexity

Could someone explain how this algorithm is `O(log(n))` and not `O(n)`?

the loop runs for all the digits in a given number. So isn't the           complexity `O(n)`?

```
 while (x != 0) {
      int pop = x % 10;
      x /= 10;
      if (rev > Integer.MAX_VALUE/10 || (rev == Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10 && pop > 7)) 
           return 0;
      if (rev < Integer.MIN_VALUE/10 || (rev == Integer.MIN_VALUE / 10 && pop < -8)) 
           return 0;
      rev = rev * 10 + pop;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `n` is. If `n` is `x` itself, a numeric value, then the complexity is `O(log(n))`. If you multiply `x` by 10, the `while` loop will only be one iteration longer, not ten times as long. Likewise, multiplying `x` by 100 will only add two iterations.

On the other hand, if there was a variable `s` which was the string representation of `x`, and `n` was the length of string `s`, then the complexity would be `O(n)`. Note that in this case, the length of `s` is proportional to `log(x)`, so the logarithm is implicit from the viewpoint of the numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought experiment:

1. The algorithm depends on the number of digits in `n`, not the value of `n`. `n = 10` takes as many iterations as `n = 99` because they both have 2 digits.
2. The number digits in `n` grows at `log(n)` rate, since adding a single digit requires `n` to be at least 10 times bigger.

Hence the algorithm has a complexity of `O(log(n))`